# PHP Yield keyword - loop iteration

Tags: php, generator, yield, post-increment

I am using PHP generator and can't explain this behavior.
This is the code I tried

```
<!-- language: PHP -->
<?php
function myfun($num1, $num2, $ctr = 1) {
    for ($i = $num1; $i <= $num2; $i =+ $ctr) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
echo 'Odd numbers: ';
foreach(myfun(1, 7, 2) as $num) {echo $num;};
?>
```

Can someone explain me this behavior using PHP yield, entering a infinite loop?

result: Odd numbers: 122222222222222222222222222222222...............

Note: $i += $ctr works as expected

result: Odd numbers: 1357

Comment: `$i =+ $ctr` is the same as `$i = $ctr`. `+ some number` is essentially a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `=+` operation, you probably meant to type `+=`, which would do the trick:

```
<?php
function myfun($num1, $num2, $ctr = 1) {
    for ($i = $num1; $i <= $num2; $i += $ctr) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
echo 'Odd numbers: ';
foreach(myfun(1, 7, 2) as $num) {echo $num;};
```

Result: `Odd numbers: 1357`

Comment: I agree with this, but why 1222222, and not 1111111??

Comment: you assign `$i` as `$num1` in the first iteration, and you call it with `1` as a value for `$num1`

Comment: 1 is the default value in case of not provided; Remove =1 (so function myfun($num1, $num2, $ctr)) in the loop definition, same behavior!!!

Comment: In the first iteration `$i` is equal to `$num1`, that's the first part of the `for()`. In the second iteration (and *all* others), it will be set to `$ctr` (which is 2). So you get one loop of `$i` being `1`, and all the next ones where it will be `2`. The loop doesn't finish, because `$i <= $num2` is never true.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i =+ $ctr
```

`=+` is not an operator. This will essentially do `$i = $ctr`.

The first time the loop occurs `$i` is set to `$ctr`, in this case this is 2. After this it is continually set to 2 and never goes higher. Hence the infinite loop. Use `+=` instead.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheVerhulst Don't blame the parser. Nothing to complain for here - infinite loop is a valid syntactic construct. And here `+` symbol is interpreted as `unary plus operator`, i.e. `$x = 10` and `$x = +10` are semantically equivalent. Parser can't know that you instead of unary plus operator wanted to write compound assignment operator. So ...